# Xpath - Search within xpath results

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath

I am using python with xpath and am getting lost in the xpath syntax. What I would like to do is to check if there is not a tag in a table in an html page. So I am using xpath to do this. Then, if there isn't this tag, do an xpath search relative to the section. I seem to be getting something working, but it kind of does the reverse and can't figure out why. Example code is below.

```
main_sections = tree.xpath('//td[@class="cars"]')

for i in range(0, len(main_sections)):
    has_no_flag = True
    for c in main_sections[i].getchildren():
        if c.tag == "span" and c.get("class") == "colorRed":
            has_no_flag = False

if has_no_flag:
     price = main_sections[i].xpath('//td[@class="cars"]/following-sibling::td[@class="price"]/span[@class="amount-value"]')
     price_str = price[0].text.strip()
```

I don't think the xpath is correct for price. Hopefully someone will be able to enlighten me :)

Comment: would you mind sharing the html in question, we can't make assumptions on the exact structure of your document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're using XPath correctly here.

Just filter the nodes you want to have and throw out your own loops and flags.

```
cars_without_tag_price = '''//td[
    @class="cars" and not(span[@class="colorRed"])
]/following-sibling::td[@class="price"]/span[@class="amount-value"]
'''

for price_node in tree.xpath(cars_without_tag_price):
    price_str = price_node.text.strip()
```

Comment: Holy moly! Thanks - I didn't think xpath could do that. Just one more question - what do the emtpy strings mean at the beginning and end of the xpath string?

Comment: You'd be surprised at the things XPath can do when it comes to picking specific nodes out of a tree. It really is worth learning beyond the basics. -- There are no empty strings in this code sample. Triple quotes are Pythons way to mark multi-line strings.

Comment: ahh yes. forgot about this. You can tell I'm very much a beginner at this at the moment :)